# SQLite in QGIS project

Tags: qgis, import, sqlite

I have exported file with no geometry, values from attribute tables, to SQLite. I manage to open it in SQLite.

But when I want to import to another QGIS project or even the same project I get an  error message.
"failure getting table metadata. Is path/file.sqlite really a Spatial Lite database?"

what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

An SQLite file is not (always) a SpatialLite database file. SpatialLite database files have extra metadata tables for spatial data.

If you create a SQLite file using, for example, the `sqlite3` command line SQL processor, or Python's `sqlite3` module, you won't get a SpatialLite database.

QGIS might be able to read the plain SQLite file as non-spatial database tables, but I can't see a native way of doing it so the solution is either going to be via ODBC or converting your plain SQLite to a SpatialLite database or another format, eg GeoPackage, which is still SQLite compatible.

Comment: thanks. How to convert from SQLite to SpatialDatabase ? Any recommendations. I have found this for ex. https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/sqlite-to-geopackage